# How can Set session message from cakephp .ctp file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, cakephp

HI I have a button on a view page like for that I have to check who is clicking that button we have different type of user on our site so we  don't want to allow a specific type of user of our site to click on that or get any changes so for that we are checking at the time of clicking who is clicking the button is the user whom we want or whom we don't want so for that I am checking session ID at the time of button click .
So what Now I want that if the user whom we don't want click on that button so they should redirect to a thanks page with a session message.
I know the way to  how to show session message from cakephp controller for this I used this:

```
**$sending = SITE_URL."thanks";
            $this->Session->setFlash(__("Sorry! You are unauthorized user. Contact us at help@example.com", true), 'default', array('class' => 'notclass'));
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.location.href='".$sending."';</script>";
            die;**
```

But when I am trying same logic in .ctp file  after my condition 
`if($this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')!='' && $this->Session->read('Auth.User.role_id')=='2'){`

```
<th></br><span style="font-family: 'proximanova semibold',Ubuntu;font-weight: normal; color: #333333;font-size: 18px;">Basic</span><br/><span>Free</span><br/>
        <div class="apply-button-search" style="float: none; margin: auto; margin-bottom: 5px;">

    <input class="profilebtn" type="button" style="width:100px !important; margin-top: 1px;" value="Start now" onclick="window.location.href='<?php e(SITE_URL."thanks");?>'">
<?php $sending = SITE_URL."thanks";
                $this->Session->setFlash(__("Sorry! You are unauthorized user. Contact us at help@example.com", true), 'default', array('class' => 'notclass'));
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.location.href='".$sending."';</script>";
                die;?>
```

I am getting this error
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method SessionHelper::setFlash() in /var/www/html/example/app/webroot/testdemo/app/views/fronts/abc.ctp on line 123`
So I just want how can I set flash message from my .ctp file with this session helper logic.
Thanks

Comment: You should understand the different between `SessionComponent` and `SessionHelper`. `Components` are extension of `Controller` and `Helpers` are extension on `View`. So, In you view file, you are actually calling `SessionHelper` and `setFlash` is not a method of `SessionHelper`.

Comment: Thanks @FazalRasel for your response let me read the difference of SessionHelper & SessionComponent

Answer (score 0):

`setFlash` is a method of `SessionComponent` which is use on `Controller`. You can use Components on View but It will good to use `$this->Session->flash();` thus `flash()` is a method of `SessionHelper`.

Answer (score 0):

If You relly need you can use [CakeSession](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-CakeSession.html) (which [is used in Session component](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-SessionComponent.html#109-127)).

There are better ways to deal with that kind of problems. Few examples:

- [prefix routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing)
- different views for every group/role
- different elements with menus/button groups/... for every group/role